# Using setState with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I don't understand the error but I don't seem to be able to use setState like usually.

This is the error I get:
Argument of type '{ [x: number]: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IState | ((prevState: Readonly, props: Readonly) => IState | Pick | null) | Pick | null'.
  Property 'inputField' is missing in type '{ [x: number]: any; }' but required in type 'Pick'.ts(2345)

```
interface IState {
  inputField: string;
}

interface IProps {}

export default class Input extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  state: IState = {
    inputField: '',
  };

  handleChange = (e: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const {name, value}: any = e.target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  };

  render() {
    const {inputField} = this.state;

    return (
      <input type="text" name="inputField" value={inputField} onChange={this.handleChange} />
    );
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's the whole point of declaring your IState interface - so that Typescript can check that you are setting the right properties with the right types.

So basically you are trying to set an unknowable (at compile time) property ([name]) and the typescript compiler is telling you that it couldn't run the function because it was missing the expected inputField property.

You probably need to add all the valid properties to your IState interface and use the property name in setState.